# can not resolve symbol 'CAMERA' in checkSelfPermission method

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

```
I need to ask for runtime permission to use camera in my fragment class.my code is like this..


int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);........
```

but,it shows-can not resolve symbol 'CAMERA'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

import below statement into your code.

```
import android.Manifest;

  int permissionCheckStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                if (permissionCheckStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
                }
```

Comment: thank you.now i get an error at  requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS); tried  FragmentCompat.requestPermissions().bt no use.

Comment: @ben10 you are getting error because you need requestpermissions

Comment: sry i got it right.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS); was enough.that extra argument-getActivity made it worse.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
        MY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST__CODE) {
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Now user should be able to use camera
    }
    else {
        // Your app will not have this permission. Turn off all functions 
        // that require this permission or it will force close like your 
        // original question
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the `cannot resolve symbol camera` is to add

```
import android.Manifest;
```

The other answers cover further issues not related to the original question.